# Mathematica Splitted List with Length values

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have, in Wolfram Mathematica 8.0, a nested list like:

```
             {{1,1,1},{0,0},{1,1,1,1,1},{0},{1,1},{0}}
```

and would like to substitute the ones with the substring lengths as follows:

```
             {{3,3,3},{0,0},{5,5,5,5,5},{0},{2,2},{0}}
```

Can anybody show me a fast functional approach to this issue?

Comment: So you don't want to count zeros? What about e.g. {0,1,0}?

Answer (score 7):

```
list = {{1, 1, 1}, {0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0}, {1, 1}, {0}};
Map[Length[#]*# &, list]

Out[193]= {{3, 3, 3}, {0, 0}, {5, 5, 5, 5, 5}, {0}, {2, 2}, {0}}
```

Comment: So, do you think you'd be interested in the new [mathematica.se] site, also? :)

Comment: @rcollyer I'm not sure (a) why you ask (I've posted there a few times already) and (b) why you ask that here (it's not really related to the query). (Also I'm assuming I am reachable by other means; if not, then I guess here is as good as any other option.) Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question though. (Maybe it's 5 o'clock somewhere...)

Comment: Sorry. The smilely was intended to indicate that it was sarcasm, especially as I asked the other answerer the same question. (And, yes I was aware that you've already posted there.)

Comment: @rcollyer I am apparently impervious to the charms of emoticons.

Answer (score 4):

If

```
list = {{1, 1, 1}, {0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0}, {1, 1}, {0}};
```

then

```
list /. {items : 1 ..} :> ConstantArray[Length[{items}], Length[{items}]]
```

(replacing all lists consisting of one or more 1s with a list of corresponding length with the length as values) gives:

```
{{3, 3, 3}, {0, 0}, {5, 5, 5, 5, 5}, {0}, {2, 2}, {0}}
```

Comment: I'd suggest these slight changes: `items:{1 ..} :> With[{l = Length@items}, ConstantArray[l, l]]` as it reduces repetition. Also, you may interested in the new [mathematica.se] site.

Answer (score 2):

Let

```
f := # /. (x_List /; Union@x=={1}) :> Table[Length@x, {Length@x}] &
```

Use as

```
f/@list
```

Better yet (and stealing part of Jan's answer):

```
f2 := # /. ConstantArray[1, Length@#] :> ConstantArray[Length@#, Length@#] &
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what variation your data may contain.  If your sublists are all monotonically zero or one then Daniel's method works.  If you need a little more speed you might use:

```
f = Compile[{{s, _Integer, 1}}, If[s[[1]] == 1, s*Length@s, s]];

f /@ list
```

If the sublists may contain other elements and/or be mixed then more testing is needed.  I'll leave testing which works best on your data to you:

```
list /. x : {1 ..} :> (ConstantArray[#, #] &@Length@x)

list /. {x : 1 ..} :> ConstantArray[+x, +x]

list /. x : {1 ..} :> x * Tr@x
```

Finally for any "code golf" fans:

```
list /. {x:1..}:>+x{x}
```

Comment: You have typos in the first and second lines of the second code block. RHSs should be `ConstantArray[Length@x, Length@x]` and
`ConstantArray[+x, +x]`.

Comment: @kguler Thanks.  I need to remember to (1) read the bloody question (2) execute my darn code.